# Using Dynamic SQL in MySQL (Sub-Query with Result of Query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure this is even possible but I know if it is, the stackoverflow community is where I'll find the answer.  I'm basically trying to pre-process some data so that I can speed up my application.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT id 
FROM data AS data1 
WHERE rangeVal < (SELECT rangeVal FROM data WHERE id = data1.id - 1)
AND actiondate >= '1980-05-18' 
AND actiondate <= '2012-05-18'
ORDER BY actiondate DESC
```

Essentially, I'm trying to get the IDs of my data only if their rangeVal is less than the rangeVal from the next day.

Any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Your query seems correct; you could use `BETWEEN '1980-05-18' AND '2012-05-18'`, but engine should be good enough to do it for you. Did you test your query? What's wrong?

Comment: What's the result you get with this query (which seems correct at first sight) ?

Comment: Just to clarify why I removed the Dynamic-SQL tag... Dynamic SQL is where a SQL command is built up dynamically. Such as introducing new JOINs or WHERE clauses. The example query in the question just uses a correlated sub-query *(the result of the sub-query is correlated to the outer query)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your days are incremental and you have a row for each day, rather than try to rely on subtracting from an incremental id, which can be highly unreliable due to row deletions and other issues, you can join against the table using the `DATE_SUB()` or `DATE_ADD()` as the join condition:

```
SELECT 
  id
FROM 
  data data_today
  /* JOIN on a date manipulation */
  JOIN data data_tomorrow ON DATE_ADD(data_today.actiondate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) = data_tomorrow.action_date
WHERE 
  data_today.rangeVal < data_tomorrow.rangeval
  AND data_today.actiondate BETWEEN '1980-05-18' AND '2012-05-18'
```

Answer (score 0):

The sub query is also fine

```
SELECT id 
FROM data AS data1 
WHERE rangeVal < 
    (
     SELECT rangeVal FROM data d2 WHERE d2.id = data1.id  AND d2.actiondate= 
     DATE_ADD(d2.action_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    )
AND actiondate BETWEEN '1980-05-18' AND '2012-05-18'
ORDER BY actiondate DESC
```